# PostgreSQL, insert fuction, check if value exists and pass that row's values in NEW on insert

Tags: postgresql

I have a table people with columns: first_name, last_name, phone_number, address. Is it possible to have a function, that on insert checks if phone_number already exists and if so, it inserts existing values (first_name and last_name) instead of what user tried to insert? It would allow new address to be insert, only existing first_name and last_name would be copied. It is quite opposite to upsert, which would update the existing row. None of these columns have constraints.

I tried to use IF EXISTS, but I actually don't know how to pass the existing values into NEW. It works with fixed values, e.g. THEN NEW.first_name = 'Jack'.

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people p WHERE p.phone_number = NEW.phone_number) THEN
       NEW.first_name = ?;
END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
INSERT INTO people(phone_number, first_name, last_name, address)
VALUES ($1,
        COALESCE((SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE phone_number = $1), $2), 
        COALESCE((SELECT last_name FROM people WHERE phone_number = $1), $3), 
        $4);
```

Comment: Thank you, although syntax that worked for me was in the end slightly different (IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people p WHERE p.phone_number = NEW.phone_number) THEN EXECUTE
       'SELECT people.first_name FROM people WHERE people.phone_number = $1' USING NEW.phone_number INTO NEW.first_name;
your insight was invaluable.

Comment: It was unclear to me where that code is located. Is that a PL/PGSQ trigger function?

Comment: Yes, it's a before insert trigger function.